# Why is my webpack bundle.js bigger than 7.58MB

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Why is my bundle.js so large?

What is wrong with my configuration file?

All my React projects tend to be incredibly large in file size (bundle.js is 7.58 mb). I have no idea why is it this large. I already have uglifyJS on, but this doesn't seem to help a lot.

Here are the details:

```
bundle.js    7.58 MB       0  [emitted]  main

index.html  942 bytes          [emitted]
```

My webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const htmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

const BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist');
const APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components');
const DATA_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'data');


const config = {
    entry: APP_DIR + '/App.jsx',
    output: {
        path: BUILD_DIR,
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?/,
                include: APP_DIR,
                loader: [
                    'babel'
                ],
                query: {
                    presets: ["es2015", "react"]
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader:'style-loader!css-loader?importLoaders=1!postcss-loader'
            },
            {
                test:/\.scss$/,
                loader:'style-loader!css-loader?importLoaders=1!postcss-loader!sass-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.html/,
                loader:'html-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(json)([\?]?.*)$/,
                include: DATA_DIR,
                loader: "file-loader",
                query:{
                    name:"data/[name].[ext]"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|svg|ttf)([\?]?.*)$/,
                loader: "file-loader",
                query:{
                    name:"asserts/fonts/[name].[ext]"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g)$/i,
                include: DATA_DIR,
                loader: "file-loader",
                query:{
                    name:"data/images/[name]-[hash:5].[ext]"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    postcss:[
        require('autoprefixer')({
            broswers:['last 5 versions']
        })
    ],
    devtool:'eval-source-map',
    devServer:{
        historyApiFallback:true,
        hot:true,
        inline:true,
        proxy:{
            '/api/*':{
                target:'http://localhost:8081',
                secure:false
            }
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compressor: {
                warnings: false
            }
        }),
        new htmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'index.html',
            template: 'index.html',
            title:'this is a title',    //一个title 属性
            inject:'body'
        })
    ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --progress --profile --colors --hot --inline --port 3000 --host 0.0.0.0",
    "dev": "webpack -d --watch",
    "webpack": "webpack -p --config webpack.config.js --colors --display-reasons --display-error-details --display-modules --sort-modules-by size"
  },
  "author": "Sharp",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.1.18",
    "react": "^0.14.3",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.3",
    "webpack": "^1.12.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.7.7",
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.27.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.10.1",
    "history": "^4.6.1",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^1.3.3",
    "react-addons-update": "^15.4.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.30.8",
    "react-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "0.0.22",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.3",
    "react-router": "^3.0.2",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-logger": "^2.8.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "remove": "^0.1.5",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.3",
    "scss-loader": "0.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.14.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.3"
  }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Caveat**: OP's config is a webpack v1 config, while my answer is for v2.

You are using the type of source maps that are contained in the bundle itself:

`devtool:'eval-source-map'`

This type of source maps is for developmnent only, so if the bundle size is huge it's not an issue. So nothing is wrong with you configuration file per se, you just have to make two separate configs (maybe both exending a base config) for [development and production](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production-build/#the-manual-way-configuring-webpack-for-multiple-environments), and use different source maps types in both.

See https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/ for source map types that should be used in production and development. For production you could use something like `cheap-source-map` or not use source maps at all.

Generally source maps can be output as a standalone bundle/chunk or be contained in the code bundle itself, and have different levels of detail, from line/column info to no source maps at all. This is up to you to decide how much debugging info you need in production and if you are ok with making your sources publicly available.

Comment: thanks!When i remove devtool:'eval-source-map' ,It becomes less than 1MB

Comment: @Ivan why use cheap source maps at all in production, what's the point? It's not like we debug in production.

Comment: @MartinMazzaDawson well for example there are services that allow you to collect stacktraces in production, or you can write your own. It may be nice to know how your code works on various platforms with different users. And then you might even want to be able to debug in production.